# adding user input to cURL in command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl, cmd

I have a small batch file to make `curl` easier to deal with.

```
@ECHO OFF
IF [%1]==[] ( SET /P usr="User ID: " ) else ( SET usr="%1" )
IF [%2]==[] ( SET /P pwd="Password: " ) else ( SET pwd="%2" )
IF [%3]==[] ( SET /P sysid="sys_id: " ) else ( SET sysid="%3" )
curl -k -u %usr%:%pwd% --header "Accept: application/json" --url https://example.com/%sysid%
PAUSE
```

When I don't add any parameters, it prompts me for `usr`, `pwd`, and `sys_id` and runs the cURL command appropriately. But when I actually add the parameters, like this...

```
C:\> getINC myName myPass 12345678
```

...it still prompts me for the password:

```
Enter host password for user 'myName':
```

If I enter the password it works fine, but `%pwd%` should be taking care of it in the first place. Can anyone help?

Comment: You command `SET usr="%1"` makes the quotation marks part of the variable value; perhaps that is the reason; the syntax `SET "usr=%1"` (note the moved opening `"`) assigns the plain value only... Instead of `IF [%1]==[]` I recommend to write `IF "%1"==""` to avoid trouble with white-spaces or special characters; and consider to use `%~1` rather than `%1` to remove potential surrounding quotes...